# geometry and fancyhdr clash

Tags: titles, fancyhdr, geometry

When I try and create a custom title page, I am having to adjust headerheight because of an Image that will go there. The same image will be in the header on the normal page, but slightly smaller, therefore I have to adjust the page settings twice. 
Furthermore, the footer has to be three lines tall.

therefore I have to use [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) and [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en), but fancyhdr seems to play tricks with the dimensions ...

The footers on the first AND second page are misaligned (too low and too high, respectively), all following pages seem to be fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} %filler text
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{maintext}
{
\lfoot{\small \textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\pagestyle{maintext}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{maintext}

\voffset -54pt
\headheight 100pt
\headsep 54pt
\textheight 545pt
%summe=645

\huge \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE}}


\end{titlepage}

\voffset -49pt
\headheight 60pt
\headsep 25pt
\textheight 609pt
%summe=645

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Don't set the dimensions manually if using `geometry`. If you can, use KOMA's facilities rather than `geometry`/`fancyhdr` but, if not, stick to those - don't mix in the manual stuff. Read the console output for warnings about the sizes `fancyhdr` needs. Don't change these for the title page or first pages of chapters/sections. Just format `titlepage` as you want - it is unlikely you need to change the page layout dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Two questions though: 1) isn't geometry made to manually fiddle with the dimensions? and 2) if I leave geometry be, then the fist page's footer is still misaligned, also the header image takes up much more space, since the inch of clearance it has to the top of the page just means tons of white space around the image gets wasted

Comment: `geometry` is used to customise the page dimensions. When you specify them manually, the package doesn't know that, it cannot track your changes and it will calculate things in ways which ignore those changes. When you say `\setlength{\headheight}{100pt}` (LaTeX syntax since you are using LaTeX), `geometry` can't take account of the change. When you say `\geometry{headheight=100pt}`, it can. Normally, you don't change the layout of the page for the title page or whatever. Although, as Bernard says, you can. But use `geometry`'s commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrheadings`:

```
\documentclass[%
  footheight=36pt% suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\logoheight
\usepackage{lipsum} %filler text
\usepackage[
    showframe,
    top=128pt,
    height=609pt,
    headheight=65pt,
    headsep=20pt
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{%
  \setlength\logoheight{\dimexpr\headheight-5pt}%
  \includegraphics[height=\logoheight]{example-image.pdf}%
}
\ifoot{\textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\small}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}
\newgeometry{
  top=192pt,
  height =545pt,
  headheight=105pt,
  headsep=49pt
}
\noindent\huge \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE}}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the page number should be aligned in the same way as in the other examples remove [t]footheight=36pt[/t] and change [t]\ifoot[/t] to

```
\ifoot{\smash{%
  \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}}}
```

[image]

Of course it is also possible to define a new page style

```
\documentclass[%
  footheight=36pt% suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newlength\logoheight
\usepackage{lipsum} %filler text
\usepackage[
    showframe,
    top=128pt,
    height=609pt,
    headheight=65pt,
    headsep=20pt
  ]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\chead{\includegraphics[height=60pt]{example-image.pdf}}
\ifoot*{\textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont\small}

\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{titlepage}{
  \ihead{\includegraphics[height=100pt]{example-image.pdf}}
  \chead{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{titlepage}
\newgeometry{
  top=192pt,
  height =545pt,
  headheight=105pt,
  headsep=49pt
}
\noindent\huge \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE}}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` commands solved the problem immediately. I'm still using `fancyhdr` though since The footer of `titleps` produces errors when the tabular environment is moved to the right. Left and Center footers accept tables without a problem... weird.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `\newgeometry` and `restoregeometry` commands, but you have to compute the `topmargin` key. The `titleps` package (from the `titlesec` bundle) works better than `fancyhdr` in this situation. Here isq a simple code. The pagestyles definition with fancyhdr is comment. To give a  try to the fancyhdr solution, uncomment the corresponding lines, and comment those using `pagestyle`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} %filler text
\usepackage{array, graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{top=128pt, height=609pt, headheight=60pt, headsep=25pt}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancypagestyle{maintext}
%{
%\lfoot{\small \textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%}
%
%\fancypagestyle{titlepage}
%{
%\chead{\includegraphics[height=100pt]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}}
%\lfoot{\small \textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{titlepage}{%
\sethead{}{\includegraphics[height=100pt]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}}{}
\setfoot{\small\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l} \textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3\end{tabular}}{}{}
}%
\newpagestyle{maintext}{%
\setfoot{\small \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}\textbf{address 1}\\address 2\\address 3\end{tabular}}{}{}
}%
\pagestyle{maintext}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \newgeometry{top=192pt, height =545pt, headheight=100pt, headsep=54pt}

  \huge \textbf{\uppercase{TITLE}}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Fancyhdr solution:

[image]

Titleps solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to change the page geometry and/or change the header dimensions if you want to place a figure on the title page.  You can simply use a 0pt height/width `picture` environment to position your figure and then the rest of your title, e.g. (Code borrowed from [Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256334/76063)):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum} %filler text
\usepackage{array, graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{top=128pt, height=609pt, headsep=25pt}

\usepackage{titleps}

\newpagestyle{maintext}{%
  \setfoot{%
    \small 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
      \textbf{address 1}\\ address 2\\ address 3
    \end{tabular}}
  {}
  {{\includegraphics[width=7mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-1x1}}}
}%
\pagestyle{maintext}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
      \put(0,8){%
        \makebox(0,0)[b]{%
          \includegraphics[width=20mm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-1x1}%
        }%
      }%
    \end{picture}
  \end{center}

  \vspace*{2em}

  \huge \textbf{TITLE}
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: thanks for that tip .. it was very useful at a different location!